# Bug within daily vote limit mechanism?

Tags: bug, voting-to-close

I reached my daily vote limit with close votes. This made me unable to enter a close review queue. But now, few hours later, I can enter the queue. Still have 13 hours to wait to actually vote.

Now, I don't mind a vote limit. I just wish not to see things needing review if I can't do anything about them.

Comment: check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147052/why-am-i-unable-to-continue-reviewing-first-posts-after-reaching-the-vote-limit

Comment: @Bala - it's marked as [meta-tag:by-design] and my point is that I was able, even when I think I shouldn't. Opposite to OP there.